# Looping through an array in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image-gallery

I have created a custom post type with an image gallery upload. Now I am trying to display the gallery on the front end. This is what I have so far that works to display 1 image, but if multiple images are uploaded all the urls get stuck in the src tag. So I'm guessing I should loop through that array and spit out each one separately? Would that be the route to go and if so how can I accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<?php
echo '<img src="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery-upload', true).'">';    
?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No posts were found. Sorry!'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

EDIT:

This is what is being returned:

```
<img src="http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F800x400-volbeat-mock1.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F1574_2_1.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F1576_2_1.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F1576_4_1.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F2244_2_1.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F300789_2349086884438_1168050047_32154880_1451576942_n.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F373795_278881222158106_278880528824842_834930_1454244548_n.jpeg%2Chttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fandreasmoulis%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2012%2F10%2F20110909-121141.jpeg">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [function reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), get_post_meta ordinarily returns an array unless the third argument is set to true. Something like this should work, more or less.

```
<?php
foreach(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery-upload') as $meta) {
  foreach(explode(',', $meta) as $src) {
    echo '<img src="'.htmlentities($src).'">';
  }
}
?>
```

EDIT: Apparently gallery-upload is stored as comma-separated values. Updated my snippet above to *hopefully* account for this.

Comment: I'll play around with it thanks. Check out my edit, that's what I got with your code. Any ideas why?

Comment: Heh, whoops. Remove the rawurlencode(...) function (see my update above) and it should fix it.

Comment: Still nothing, it's returning everything within one <img src=""> So it's producing all the links. Just not in separate image tags.

Comment: Ah! So looking at the $src it returned, it seems to be giving you a comma-separated list of values. Take a look at my updated snippet.

Comment: You are amazing good sir! I appreciate the help. Forgot about explode!